# Amount of Rows in SQL database from user from each month (to C# Graph)

Tags: c#, sql

Re-edit:

I hope to make myself a bit more clear, sorry for any trouble. Currently I am trying to get the total amount of tickets that were created each month and display them on a graph in my C# Application.

I have a database which stores all the ticket information including when they were completed. I need to figure out to display how many tickets were created per month on my graph. I need to find how to save the SQL result of:

```
SELECT YEAR(CompletedOn) y, MONTH(CompletedOn) m, COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE Username=@username GROUP BY y, m
```

*(Which works perfectly in SQL! Many thanks for those who suggested)*

To display on my graph as such in C#:

```
chart1.Series["Month"].Points.AddXY("Jan", **MONTH 1 from SQL GROUP AS SHOWN ABOVE**);
chart1.Series["Month"].Points.AddXY("Feb", **MONTH 2 from SQL GROUP AS SHOWN ABOVE**);
```

Should I be using MySqlDataReader? ExecuteReader? ExectureNonQuery?

```
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string getAmountOfTickets = "SELECT YEAR(CompletedOn) y, MONTH(CompletedOn) m, COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE Username=@username GROUP BY y, m";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getAmountOfTickets, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", chartUser);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CommonGlobalVariables.graph_jan = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
                conn.Close();
                //Debug Test
                MessageBox.Show("Month 1 = " + CommonGlobalVariables.graph_jan);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {

            }
        }

chart1.Series["Month"].Points.AddXY("Jan", CommonGlobalVariables.graph_jan);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help better explain what you want to do.  As a note, you could just replace `select *` with `select count(*)`.

Comment: A simple example would be 20 rows of data for a computer repair (Ticket containing User/Name of Customer, Device ID, Completed Date etc..). What if a few rows of data had a completed date in Jan. I need to get total amount of how many tickets were completed on January. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like basic aggregation.

You need to use `COUNT(*)` , for specific month:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM tickets
WHERE month(CompletedOn)=1
```

For all month's :

```
SELECT month(CompletedOn) as mnth , count(*)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY mnth
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've +'ed you but it doesn't display until I have 15+ rep. I've tried to re-edit my question so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

This query gets the ticket count of user 'foobar' for each month of each year.

```
SELECT YEAR(CompletedOn) y, MONTH(CompletedOn) m, COUNT(*) FROM tickets 
WHERE UserName='foobar'
GROUP BY y, m
```

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. I need to return the number of tickets that were logged for each month

Comment: Many thanks, I've +'ed you but it doesn't display until I have 15+ rep. I've tried to re-edit my question so it is readable.